# How to use path of current conda environment's python as shebang for a script?

Tags: python, environment-variables, conda, environment, shebang

Let's say you have 2 conda environments: `py3_env` and `py3_clone_env`

If you have a `script.py` with the following structure:

```
#![shebang]
import sys
def main():
    print("hello world", file=sys.stdout)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Is it possible to have the shebang be a variable that is determined from the current conda environment?**

For example:

From `py3_env` environment:

```
#!~/anaconda/envs/py3_env/bin/python
```

and from `py3_clone_env` environment:

```
#!~/anaconda/envs/py3_clone_env/bin/python
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess what you need is `#!/usr/bin/env python`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

In this case, `python` is the `python` based on current `PATH` environment variables. So it is your current virtualenv's python.

Comment: Woah!  I always wondered why people have always added that.  Thanks a lot.