# Run a script with its own environment from another script with a different environment (Windows 10)

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, shebang

I have been stuck on this problem for a while now and I have tried different solutions online but still cannot get it resolved. I already tried these out:

[How to run a python script with its environment from another script with another environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55882496/how-to-run-a-python-script-with-its-environment-from-another-script-with-another)

[How to use path of current conda environment's python as shebang for a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52087621/how-to-use-path-of-current-conda-environments-python-as-shebang-for-a-script)

[How do I activate a conda env in a subshell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41914739/how-do-i-activate-a-conda-env-in-a-subshell)

I have a `script1.py` which uses conda environment `my_env1` and calls with CLI to another script `script2.py` that requires `my_env2` (also conda environment). `script2.py` is called from `script1.py` which is activated with `my_env1`. `script1.py` works fine when I activate `my_env2`, but does not work when I run it with `my_env1`.

In my `script2.py`, I have used following 2 Shebangs separately (but none of them seem to work):

```
#!C:/Users/<user_name>/.conda/envs conda run -n my_env2 python
#!C:/Users/<user_name>/.conda/envs/my_env2 python
```

In conda environments, `my_env2` and `my_env1`, there is no `bin` folder, so I tried using `conda install --name <env_name> python`; still doesn't solve it. Any help on this would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I tried this hack also: `C:/Users/<user_name>/.conda/envs/my_env2/python script1.py`, but still no progress.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52008516/how-do-i-set-default-app-for-a-file-extension-to-an-exe-on-windows-10-after/52009412#52009412.

Comment: How are you calling `script2` from `script1`? Are they sharing objects? If not, maybe you could do a custom shell calling  python from `my_env2 ` . You can check this on [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html)

Comment: @Ivan script1 uses CLI like `subprocess.check_call(['python', path/to/script2.py])`. They are not sharing any objects.

Comment: Right now I can't check this in my PC, but can you try something like this? `subprocess.check_call(['C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/envs/my_env2/python', path/to/script2.py]) `

Comment: @Ivan there is no environment under `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs`; path is found though. All environments are under 'C:/Users/<user_name>/.conda/envs'. And as I put on the first comment, I already tried that out.